# Having Apex Application converted from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: oracle-apex

I require a solution to this issue.

I have to Secure my Apex Application and I have the steps, in Instance Settings, to make the necessary changes on that end.
However, I need be able to apply the Wildcard (SSL) Certificate <*forgive me if I called it the wrong name*> inside of Apex.

**NOTE: the application was note built with IIS implemented, so maybe there's a way to do it within APEX.**

Please help with any solutions that can be implemented.

Comment: What version of APEX are you using, and what (if any) application server for ORDS?

Comment: Oracle APEX 22.1.0 is the version